# Is it really possible to be "half dead"?

Tags: etymology, expressions, colloquialisms, logic

It is not all-too-rare to hear of someone being "*half-dead*," but is that logical, or possible?

If so, how do you determine just how dead, percentage-wise, a person is?

If it's possible to be 50% dead, then it must also be possible to be 7% dead, 42% dead, etc. Or even beyond integers, what about being 3.14% dead?

If that were so, surely medical science would be able to tell you that the patient is "*14.3% dead, but stable*" (so, if said patient continues in such a condition, he will live forever, but not feel all that chipper), or "*37.7% dead, and declining rapidly*" or "*29.4% dead, but gradually improving*" and so on.

Are the old less alive than the young? Is old age a matter of the percentage of aliveness gradually diminishing?

IOW, a person is either alive or dead, right? They are either 100% alive, or 0% alive. Being "half dead" makes no sense. From whence did this oddly even expression originate?

And why is the expression *"half dead*" instead of "*half alive*", anyway? Is this an optimist ("*glass half full*") vs. pessimist ("*glass half empty*") thing? Would you rather be told you were 14.3% dead ("***Dang, I'm 1/7th dead!!! I wonder which 7th?!?***") or that you were 85.7% alive ("***Hey, I'm 6/7th alive! I pretty much rock!!!***")

Comment: I think it's more to do with how far down the path of becoming dead you are.  If I have been beaten for 2 hours and if the beating continues for another 2 hours I will die then maybe I'm half-dead at the 2 hour mark.  But it's usually hyperbole.

Comment: Half-dead is just a metaphorical expression that describes someone's exhaustion or weakness.

Comment: @Rathony: I have heard it far more often in the sense Jim mentioned, that is to write, someone being half-dead from a beating or a skimobile accident or such.

Comment: It's qualitative, not quantitative. It's just a way of using hyperbole to make a point that someone is severely injured and likely close to death.

Comment: Yes, I know. You get exhausted/weakened when you get beaten up or involved in any accident. I think @Nonnal explained well above.

Comment: I think there are two different things here. One is a medical/philosophical definition of what constitutes death. This may be a rather more uncertain matter than it once was, given the modern use of life-support machines. Only then could we determine whether death could be partially the case. But the other matter concerns the idiomatic language form *half-dead*. The hyperbole does exist and its meaning is movable depending on circumstances. It has very little to do with actual death, whether partial or complete.

Comment: What happens if a body is deep frozen. before death, with the expectation of eventual resuscitation. Is the frozen person "dead"? It could have legal implications, among other things. Could probate be effected?

Comment: @WS2: Could death and "suspended animation" be, at least in some cases, synonymous?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon There must be some case law on this.

Comment: My cell phone tells me when its battery is 42% dead.

Comment: Read the [etymonline page on dead](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dead&allowed_in_frame=0) and I think you'll understand the origins of the term half-dead much better.

Comment: @StevenLittman I'm glad I don't have any part of me which tells me when I'm 42% dead!

Comment: I recall a TV documentary piece on brain surgery performed when the patient's blood had been cooled to the point that his heart stopped and his brain exhibited no electrical activity.  The reporter asked the surgeon whether the patient was dead.  The surgeon said, "It depends on whether he wakes up when we re-warm his blood."

Comment: @deadrat: You mean 58%, right?

Comment: @WS2 In the US, a person isn't legally dead until a death certificate has been issued (or in the case of the missing, a court order has been entered).

Comment: @StevenLittman You're a glass-half-empty kind of guy. You cell phone is telling you its battery is 58% alive. Feel better now?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Jeez, I can't even do arithmetic now.  What percentage of brain dead does that make me?

Comment: So there's legally dead in addition to medically dead, which is an either/or thing (all or nothing). A cat in Oakland once told me I was dead, but I think that was a threat or prediction rather than an assessment. So far, at least, he was wrong.

Comment: Idioms are often non-compositional (they don't mean what the sum of their parts would mean). 'Half dead' is an idiom; it doesn't follow the same logic as 'half full' say. But this is easily found by checking in a dictionary; CDO and Collins certainly define the string. // Haven't you ever 'boiled a kettle'?

Comment: Is anyone else having *Princess Bride* quotes going through their head right now?  "He's only mostly dead.  If he were all dead there's only one thing to do.  Go through his pockets and look for loose change."

Comment: @cobaltduck: One of the greatest and most quotable flicks of all time!

Comment: @deadrat Not wishing to split hairs, but I am sure the person has been legally dead from the time of death as stated on the death certificate. At least I'm sure that is the position under English law. But would a doctor issue a death certificate for a person frozen before death?

Comment: @B.Clay Shannon "a cat in Oakland"....brings to mind Schrodinger's cat.  Is it alive or dead or, because it could be either,50/50 according to the gedanken experiment,  50% alive?

Comment: @WS2 Not to worry; I'm a big fan of hair splitting.  The person's time of death is that stated on the death certificate, which isn't official until the issuance some time later.  I think we're in violent agreement.

Comment: @ab2 Schrodinger's cat isn't one or the other; it's a mixture of both until someone looks in the box.  The percentage is determined by the quantum calculation of the trigger, which may or may not be 50%.

Comment: @deadrat  I know, but I couldn't resist.

Comment: @ab2 Apparently, neither could I.

Comment: We do not die all at once. We die a piece at a time.

Comment: People *do* use the phrase "half alive."  Jewel used it in the lyrics of *You Were Meant For Me*,  "I'm half alive but I feel mostly dead."  There's some nice wordplay there, just in the balance of "half alive" and "mostly dead", but there's nothing usual about "half alive."

Comment: Sometimes deadness can be precisely measured: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/99_and_44/100%25_Dead

Comment: I find it difficult to consider this as a serious question. "Half-dead" is an obvious metaphor, why is it hard to treat it as such ? And wondering whether "half-dead" is logical - or even possible - or even how to determine the degree of "deadness" ?? It's like wondering whether it's possible / logical to let a "show go on" if there was no show, or how can a bribe be passed "under the table" if there is no table.

Comment: No surprise that your most active account is Stack Overflow... English is not assembly language.  The semantics are rather more subtle and fluid. ;)

Comment: I am conviced that "Half-dead" is used over "Half-alive" because there would be issues with the Valve Corporation.

Comment: FWIW, you have same idiom at least in Italian and Spanish. And nobody would ever question that. Get it as _almost dead_ ^^

Comment: @cobaltduck - I'm vaguely recalling some lyrics in the *Monty Python and the Holy Grail" musical along the lines of "I'm not dead yet".

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, to comment on the example in your question, you could be 3.14 % dead from eating too much pi.

Comment: At least it's hilarious! Hahahahaha.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Much of the power of English is in its ability to be enhanced and empowered by metaphor.  You are advocating the abolishment of metaphor, a step which would leave the English language half dead.

Comment: You're assuming it's not already half dead.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - Ah, but it's one-and-a-half times alive to start with, so it works out to 1.

Comment: @HotLicks that would leave it three quarters alive then, I think you will find ...

Comment: @martin - No, language death is only additive, not multiplicative.

Comment: @HotLicks ah, I see. Do you have a ref. for that?

Comment: @martin - https://books.google.com/books?id=Ml-RYut8OlMC&pg=PA319&lpg=PA319&dq=additive+nature+of+language&source=bl&ots=7tEFEaYG_6&sig=OayNdn_QMfQSCnXUn8XZbdLFOaU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_t-yGudLJAhWB1R4KHYVWD2sQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=additive%20nature%20of%20language&f=false

Comment: @HotLicks well, I have to hand it to you, I didn't expect that!

Comment: @B.ClayShannon You'd think English is already half dead for whatever reason. However, consider this, there are countries where they don't teach the grammar of their own language. I asked grown ups in this country to find the verb, subject or object in a sentence written in their own language. They could not, let alone not understanding the concept of a sentence or the subject of a sentence all together. People construct sentences without a subject, object or even a verb. Also there are even languages "literally" dying.

Comment: @Ascendant - Yep.  [By one account](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20120531-can-we-save-our-dying-languages) a language dies every 14 days.

Comment: @Ascendant: Out of curiosity, may I know what language is that?

Comment: @Ascendant: "there are countries where they don't teach the grammar of their own language" -- the UK, for example. OK, so subject-verb-object is taught, but beyond very simple basics I hardly got any systematic teaching in grammar at all until I started learning languages other than English. But dissecting something isn't *exactly* the same thing as keeping it alive ;-)

Comment: @justhalf, Korean

Comment: @SteveJessop Simply dissecting was not what I said. But rather it's the study of the language. Here in Korea, kids don't learn conjunctions. When you use "and" you link two of the same part of speech. When you use "or" , for example, that means you can choose only one of the two, not both. These are either not taught entirely or the emphasis is very light that it's mentioned briefly, overlooked and/or forgotten.

Comment: @Ascendant: ah, I read your comment as that the language itself has no concept of subject and verbs. Apparently it's *some grown-ups* that doesn't know the concept of subject and verbs, not the property of the language.

Comment: I didn't mean that the language inherently misses those features. You could certainly construct a Korean sentence with a subject, verb, object or even some determiners. But that would sound very odd and that's not how the language is practiced. Interestingly, when I hear a sentence without a subject, I ask the speaker to tell me what/who the subject is. Most of the times, there is a pause and ultimately the speaker is unable to identify the subject.

Comment: @Ascendant The human race managed to speak and develop languages for many millennia without anyone ever teaching them what a noun, verb, subject, or sentence is. That ultimately means very, very little. People are perfectly capable of constructing correct grammatical structures without having the faintest idea what they are.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your latter question, it has more to do with point of reference than optimism vs. pessimism.  I know many optimists and many pessimists, but I have rarely heard *half-alive*.

We are all alive--that is, all of us who are creating speech and using expressions like *half-dead* or *half-alive* are currently alive.  To say we are *half-alive* does not create the same internal juxtaposition of the speaker's status, than if the speaker said *half-dead*.  We're more used to being around people who are alive - at least most of us - so *half-dead* serves to better capture someone's attention.

Comment: isn't half-alive this funny game with Dr. Gordon Freeman, who works at the Black Mesa Research Facility? ;-)

Comment: @SatelliteSD Then there's the groundbreaking sequel "alive". Everybody is still waiting for "alive-and-a-half".

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a right question in a wrong forum. Everything can't be quantified in digits. Certain things are more experienced and felt then logically put across in an equation.There are layers to a person, not just internally, but also externally: This is the aura and the seven fields which form a part of a human body. When there is too much damage to these levels,( why that happens, is another in-depth discussion) the outer aura which 'holds' the inner being safe and enclosed, is damaged.Then there is another aspect: These are soul fragments which get lost when we attach ourselves to something too deeply and can't pull back sometimes.Those also leave us feeling 'partly dead' because that fragment of your soul which was a part of you, now is invested deeply in a relationship, person, cause etc.. which over takes you so much, it takes precedence over all of your existence and anything else in your life. Sometimes in very rare cases, and though this is not a direct answer to the question, but there are instances when the auric field is so damaged,  external energies come imbalance and 'take over' which leaves the person feeling groggy, confused and not feeling like 'himself', and one often proclaims, the real me feels 'dead'. So yes, it is possible to feel 'half dead'.But the way to know about this deeper, is to know yourself and go deeper and gain knowledge on these subjects if a literal search is the seek.

Comment: "soul fragments which get lost when we attach ourselves to something too deeply" - this puts me in mind of Ben Jonson's poem "On My First Son"

Answer (score 0):

Are we to ignore the great difference between 'not all-too-rare' which doesn't and 'not too rare' which could fit here, please?

Either way, there might be 37 ways of classifying someone as half dead including, for a trite example, chop off two limbs and extract every other internal organ… perform a partial lobotomy, if you need to make up the weight.

More usefully, medical writers like https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=lyall+watson+the+romeo+error&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=lyall+watson+the+romeo+error&aqs=chrome..69i57.10119j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 have been telling us for a good 40 years that two things don't work.

No definition of life doesn't include several things 'everyone knows' are dead and much more importantly here…

No definition of death doesn't include several things 'everyone knows' are alive…